# laravel eloquent relationships queries

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables 
1)users 
{ id, password } 
2)expertise { id, expertise}

the relationship I have is

**Models**

Expertise.php

```
function User()
{

  $this->hasOne('Expertise');

}
```

User.php

```
 function Expertise()
 {
  $this->hasOne('User');

 }
```

So how can I query using Eloquent to get the first 10 users with a certain expertise?
I want to join users.id = expertise.id and get the first 10 people with a specified expertise (Where clause).

Beginner to laravel, I've checked other sources but was not successful

Answer (score 4):

Right now you are having a problem with the way that you modeled your data. If you have a one-to-one relationship the best practice to model it is to have one entity store the id of the other. The Laravel convention for this is to have a column named `<model>_id`:

```
Users
| id | password |

Expertises
| id | expertise | user_id |
```

Then in your models you can do this:

### Models

Expertise.php

```
class Expertise extends Eloquent
{

    public function User()
    {
          // because expertise has a column user_id
          // expertise belongs to user
          return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

     public function Expertise()
     {
          // because expertise is the one with the column 
          // user_id, user has one expertise
          return $this->hasOne('Expertise');
     }
}
```

### The Query

After you have all this set up, to be able to query the first 10 users with a certain expertise you can do this.

```
$users = User::whereHas('Expertise', function($q)
         {
               $q->where('expertise', '=', <expertise you are looking for>)
         })
          ->take(10)
          ->get();
```

To get a further reading in querying relationships in Laravel please take a look at this:

[Laravel - Querying Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)

### Keep in mind

keep in mind that the tables name must be plural, if not then you should specify the name of the table inside the model:

```
protected $table = 'expertise';
```

Comment: You defined the hasone and belongsto vise versa. User doesnt belong to user. User hasone expertise and expirtise belongs to user

Comment: @Pelevet if you look closely I'm defining a method called `User()` inside the Expertise.php model. Going to update the code so It reflects what I'm saying more clearly.

Comment: I am sorry that i overlooked modelnames thanks for clearance..(upvoted)

Comment: @gpopoteur  hey brother, I would really appreciate your help. But how would I pull 10 RANDOM users with a certain skill. Would really appreciate it, please help. Thanks

Comment: @roy 10 RANDOM users or the FIRST 10 users as you requested in the question?